# SQLAlchemy does not detect any existing table in postgres db

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a local postgres DB with a couple of tables and want to reflect their structure into Python.

```
import sqlalchemy.ext.automap as am
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

base_automap_schema: am.AutomapBase = am.automap_base()
engine = create_engine("postgresql+psycopg://user:pw@localhost:5432/db")
engine.echo = True
engine.connect()

# reflect the tables
base_automap_schema.prepare(autoload_with=engine)

print(base_automap_schema.classes.keys())
print(base_automap_schema.metadata.tables)
```

output is lots of SQL plus

```
[]
FacadeDict({})
```

Seems like my tables are not detected. But why?

I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76759072/sqlalchemy-automap-not-loading-table) that sometimes this happens due to a missing primary key, but all of my tables have it. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.manufacturer
(
    "manu_ID" integer NOT NULL,
    manu_name character varying[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "manu_ID" PRIMARY KEY ("manu_ID")
)
```

What else could be the problem?

Comment: just double checking, your database is really called db ? and you just masked user and pw for online forum and in reality you send the actual username and password?

Comment: Thanks for checking back. Actually, "db" is also masked. Yes, I used the correct username, pw, and dbname as far as I know. Is there any way to check whether the connection was established correctly?

Comment: engine connect should give you a cursor i believe. and with that one can run sql queries

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to query data from that and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you, @dre-hh, your comment helped me to debug my problem.

Comment: the code looked legit, hence that is the only thing i could think of, connection is somehow not established

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was actually a permissions error in the background which the `prepare` function didn't show.

You can check whether your sqlalchemy connection works like this:

```
connection: Connection
with engine.connect() as connection:
    connection.execute(text("select * from <your_schema>.<your_table>"))
```

If you get a message like "Permission denied", you know the error is not your code, but in your database users setup.